# Open popup in multi monitor system in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, multiple-monitors

I am working on an application which supports IE 7 only. I am trying to open a new external window in multi monitor system. I have applied all fixes provided in different forums but none of them is working in IE 7.

I need to open the external window in the monitor in which it was opened and then centrally allign it. The code that I am using is:

```
function openWindow( url,target )
 {
     var windowWidth = 1050;
     var windowHeight = 580;

     var screenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
     var screenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;
     var divWidth = document.getElementById("div1").offsetWidth;
     var left = screenLeft+divWidth/2-windowWidth/2;
     var windowFeatures = 'resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width='+windowWidth+',height='+windowHeight+' ';
     var tkmWindow = window.open(url, target,windowFeatures);
     tkmWindow.moveTo(left,screenTop);
     tkmWindow.focus();          
 }

<div id="div1">
<dmf:body width="1150" height="680" showdialogevent='true' cssclass='contentBackground'>
    <dmf:panel name="pnl">
        <dmf:label name = "lbl" nlsid="MSG_WINDOW_DESC" />
    </dmf:panel>        
</dmf:body>
</div>
```

The moveTo() function is not working in IE7. I have also added **meta** tag to force chrome compatibility which did not work as well.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
```

Can anyone suggest a possible fix for this issue?

Comment: if the app is `IE 7 only` why would you `force chrome compatibility`

Comment: The moveTo function was not working in IE7. So I thought that I'll enforce chrome compatbility to make it work. Anyways, if you have an alternative solution, you can always pitch that in.